# Run-Time Error'1004';Method'SaveAs'of object'_Workbook"Failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying use my Material order template to sending email to a team group and saving the file to a specific location with a specific name on the Excel file based on the cell range.

However, everything else work fine except the the code, `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=Path & fileName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlNormal.` I got yellow high-lined on the code above. it wont allow me save the file to the folder with new name.

Here the code

```
Private Sub cmdNot_Click()

    If Application.UserName = "Ryan Tory" Then

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim mSubject As String
    Dim signature As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim mBody As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim mailTo As String
    Set ws = Sheets("MRO")
    fname = ws.Range("B4")
    mSubject = "MRO Template" & "  For  " & Range("C6").Value
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    'mBody = "\\000-Draft\Material Request\Manufacturing Change Order.xlsm" & "  For  " & Range("C6").Value
    mBody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                  "Dear Team,<br><br>" & _
                  "Please open the file from below link and put your signature on the respective cell after you completed your task.<br><B>" & _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
                  "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
                  "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                  """>Link to the file</A>" & _
                  "<br><br>Best Regards," & _
                  "<br><br></font>"

    With OutMail
    .display
    End With
    signature = OutMail.body
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With


    With OutMail
        '.To = "email"
        .To = "materials@OFTMG.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = mSubject & " For "
        '.body = "Dear Team," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please open the file from below link and put your signature on the respective cell and save the sheet"
        '.htmlbody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .htmlbody = mBody
        '.Attachments.Add fileName
        .display
    End With
    'ws.PageSetup.RightHeader = "&""Calibri,italic""&11& " & ws.Range("A1")
    ws.Protect ("MRO")
    ws.Protect ("MRO")
    Path = "\\000-Draft\Kaizen Training\Material Request\New\"
    fileName = Range("C6")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=Path & fileName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
        On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
     End With

Else
MsgBox "You are not authorised to send MRO form, please check with MRO Owner", vbInformation
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I figure out by myself. here the new code.                                                                       



fileName = Range("C6").Value & Format(Now(), " mm-dd-yyyy hh_mm AM/PM")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fileName:=Path & fileName & ".xlsm"
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Close